# Find the best value in list on the basis of 2 parameters

Tags: python, normalization

I have 2 lists, one containing the distances to particular points, and another containing the means of a distribution of different values in 2-D space. Another list contains the attributes that map to these 2 lists in the same order. 
e.g. `list1 = [a, b, c, d]` 
`list2 = [10, 12, 45, 10]` -> distance of each to a particular point 
`list3 = [12.5, 17.5, 1.87, 34.4]` -> Mean of values pertaining to each of a, b, c and d.

I want to return the best value of list1 based on the minimum distance in list2 and highest mean in list 3. But I don't wish to sort them based on any priority (list 1 first and then 2 or vice versa). I want to return the best as a combination of the values in lists 2 and 3. Sorting the lists isn't the way to do that. I tried normalizing the values and adding them, but I don't know whether that is the correct approach. What is the best way to return the relevant list index?

Answer (score 0):

You can zip the three lists into one list of tuples and then retrieve the maximal tuple using the first element of each tuple as the key:

```
larges = max(zip(list1, list2, list3), key=lambda x:x[0])
#('d', 10, 34.4)
```